# Laravel function in model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel model with a simple function in it. But for some reason I get this error:

> Relationship method must return an object of type
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

Here is my Model:

```
class Dish extends Model
{
    public function sum() {
        return $this->attributes['begin'] + 10;  
    }
}
```

In my controller I do:

```
$model->sum();
```

Anyone knows how I can add the function to my model?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: where does $this point to?

Comment: Are you sure that error is for that line of code?

Comment: Are you trying to load this as a relationship ? Like `$model = Dish::with('sum')->where('id', 3)->first();` or something ?

Comment: Instead of `$this->attributes['begin'] + 10`, could you just do `$this->begin + 10`?  Not sure why that would be a problem, but it's a hunch.  Laravel thinks it's getting an eloquent relationship here, see Simon's comment above.

Comment: Could you show your entire relevant controller code? Nothing wrong with your function or with your call. Sure that the error stack is pointing to this line?

Answer (score 1):

If the calculation will be performed with the model data, you do not need to use `$this->attributes` to get the model data, that way it actually makes it a bit more "dirty". the cleanest way it will be as mention in the comments:

```
public function sumBegin($default = 10)
{
    return $this->begin + $default;
}
```

that way we take the `begin` for the current model being called.